# Azure Devops YAML - Dynamic Condition Evaluation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am attempting to use a condition to break out of a loop based on the result of a sql query. So I am assigning the query output to a variable "sqloutput" and if that value is empty string go around again. I have confirmed that the query is outputting a value however on subsequent loops the variable is still evaluating to NULL.

Also tried to explicitly declare the variable to no avail.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: loop
  type: object
  default :  ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]

stages:
- stage: WaitforProcessing
  displayName: Wait For Processing
  jobs: 
  - deployment: Deployment 
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: 'Client_Data_Tests'
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - ${{each Looptimes in parameters.loop}}:
            - task: PowerShell@2
              name: checkImportProgress${{ Looptimes }}
              condition:  and(succeeded(), eq(variables['sqloutput'], ''))
              displayName: Check if job finished 
              inputs:
                targetType: inline
                script: |
                  $query = "IF EXISTS (select 1 from Job where JobFinishTime is null)
                              BEGIN
                                select '' as result
                              END
                              ELSE
                                select '1' as result
                              "
                  $sqloutput = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $query -ServerInstance "$(DB_SERVER)" -Database "$(DB_DATABASE)" -Username "$(DB_USERNAME)" -Password "$(DB_PASSWORD)" -QueryTimeout 36000 -Verbose
                  $value = $sqloutput["result"]
                  Write-Host $value
                  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sqloutput]$value"
            - task: PowerShell@2
              condition:  and(succeeded(), eq(variables['sqloutput'], ''))
              displayName: 'Sleep for 30 seconds'
              inputs:
                targetType: inline
                script: |
                  Start-Sleep 30
```

Comment: Are you sure the `$value` variable is not null or empty ? I have tried by replacing your first script with only `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sqloutput]Hello"` and it is evaluating properly in subsequent tasks.

Comment: On another note, you could have the loop logic inside the same script ? Any reason in particular to split that into multiple tasks ?

Comment: @Thomas Confirmed as the following line `Write-Host $value`  write the value of 1

Comment: But when `$value = 1` it breaks the loop so there is no subsequent tasks to be executed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below YAML should work.

```
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A
    displayName: SQL generate variable
    steps:
    - powershell: |
          $value = 'somevalue'
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sqloutput;isOutput=true]$value"
      name: setvarStep
    - script: echo $(setvarStep.sqloutput)
      name: echovar

  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    displayName: Use variable that SQL script output as condition
    variables:
      myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setvarStep.sqloutput'] ]  # map in the variable
      myvar: true    
    condition: eq(variables['myVarFromJobA'],'somevalue')
    steps:
    - script: echo $(myVarFromJobA)
      name: echovar
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Whilst not exactly how I implemented it the targeting of the condition was the actual problem `condition: eq(variables['checkImportProgress${{Looptimes}}.sqloutput'],'')`